# Global variable is not updated if it is from other .py file

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import

As you know, the code:

```
var = "flower"
def update():
    global var
    var = "forest"

update()
print(var)
```

will properly modify the variable var, but if you do in from other file, like :

```
#global_var_update.py file:

var = "flower"

def update():
    global var
    var = "forest"

#update()
print(var)
```

And other file:

```
from global_var_update import *


update()
print(var)
```

this will Not update the variable( it will remain "flower"
What is the reason of this behavior and how to have this funtionality properly?
thanks for answers.

Comment: Importing `var` from the other .py only creates variable named `var` in the importing script — so changing it in the other script doesn't change the variable with the same name in the current script.

Comment: wow thanks, i did not know that, it is realy strange implicit feature what must not be in good language

Answer (score -1):

Well, using the Global method is a very bad idea ;-; if you want it to work correctly, you should write your function in the form of :

```
#global_var_update.py file:
var = "flower"
def update(vur):
   vur = "forest"
   return vur
```

And other file:

```
from global_var_update import *


update(var)
```

Hope it'll help you :D

Comment: no, the update will be only if you use var=update(var). Howewer i do not want for importer of this code to use assignment, since the var variable has some default context and i want to reduce unessesary writing. 
Maybe it will work if i declare it static inside a class.
Still i would like to know the reason of this behaviour

Comment: Well, check the function and you can see that there is line that modify the var variable, even if you dont write var=update(var). The solution that i proposed you works.